# Agregar cuantiles en columnas individuales en un data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

tengo un df que agrupa por columnas categorías de uso valores de magnesio (`MgClas <-`), para el cual muestro un pequeño conjunto:

```
MgClas <- structure(list(`Pasto natural` = c(35.4599723815948, 40.9176177978559, 
57.0448913574175, 52.0848350524841, 40.7783584594669), `Vegetación arbustiva baja (matorral y/o guamil)` = c(48.9271583557173, 
55.5261611938565, 73.8693389892629, 84.33711242675, 68.0492095947248
), `Lago, laguna o laguneta` = c(48.8868064880388, 62.1137161254919, 
66.3751754760763, 65.9331207275317, 60.0354423522857), `Humedal con vegetación` = c(37.4173583984386, 
47.161090850833, 60.7412071228023, 53.5338668823206, 86.9731750488289
), `Bosque latifoliado` = c(60.0262451171882, 61.3520660400344, 
77.8049087524386, 73.102416992189, 75.5364685058617)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

en base al anterior df busco generar otro df (`Resumen <-`) con medidas estadísticas descriptivas ej:

```
    Resumen <- structure(list(cod = 1:5, Categoria = c("Pasto natural", "Vegetación arbustiva baja (matorral y/o guamil)", 
"Lago, laguna o laguneta", "Humedal con vegetación", "Bosque latifoliado"
), Media = list(`Pasto natural` = 60.6433142245349, `Vegetación arbustiva baja (matorral y/o guamil)` = 48.1334826260852, 
    `Lago, laguna o laguneta` = 186.455646511974, `Humedal con vegetación` = 83.4838888877394, 
    `Bosque latifoliado` = 79.8221952277256)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

la media que ya esta en el anterior la he agregado asi:

```
Resumen$Media <- lapply(MgClas[, 1:90], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

claro solo he mostrado 5 de las 90 que tengo.
Pero también requiero agregar los valores de: Min, Q1, Mediana, Q3, Max, que he podido generar asi:

```
lapply(MgClas[, 1:90], quantile, na.rm = TRUE)
```

p.ej

```
  #$`Pasto natural`
  #0%        25%        50%        75%       100% 
  #6.204263  40.604569  63.783752  78.122543 263.982422 

  #$`...`
  #...
  #...
```

pero no puedo incorporarlas al df (`Resumen <-`) como columnas individuales  con su respectivo rotulo  que al realizarlo inocentemente de manera similar se ven asi:

```
Resumen$cuantiles <- lapply(MgClas[, 1:90], quantile, na.rm = TRUE)

#                      cuantiles
#1 6.204263, 40.604569, 63.783752,  78.122543, 263.982422
#2 5.812799, 22.752466, 41.894066,  70.711525, 222.325439
#3 19.08643, 127.53591, 230.61692,  238.30014, 271.25128
#4 15.39139, 68.42927,  84.21660,   97.98119,  231.31342
#5 5.920248, 63.701736, 84.840561,  97.543610, 270.748047
```

de que forma podría agregar cada uno en columnas individuales y el rotulo respectivo (Min, Q1, Mediana, Q3, Max)

gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien la respuesta de Rolando es perfecta para cubrir tu requerimiento, me atrevo a darte una respuesta usando la familia de paquetes `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

MgClas %>% 
    mutate(nr = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-nr) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(value), 
                 funs(media = mean,
                      min,
                      max,
                      mediana = median,
                      quantile = list(as.tibble(as.list(quantile(., probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)))))
                      )
    ) %>% 
    unnest(quantile)

# A tibble: 5 x 8
  name                                    media   min   max mediana `25%` `50%` `75%`
  <chr>                                   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Bosque latifoliado                       69.6  60.0  77.8    73.1  61.4  73.1  75.5
2 Humedal con vegetación                   57.2  37.4  87.0    53.5  47.2  53.5  60.7
3 Lago, laguna o laguneta                  60.7  48.9  66.4    62.1  60.0  62.1  65.9
4 Pasto natural                            45.3  35.5  57.0    40.9  40.8  40.9  52.1
5 Vegetación arbustiva baja (matorral y/~  66.1  48.9  84.3    68.0  55.5  68.0  73.9
```

Comentarios

- Transformamos la estructura "ancha" origina a una "larga" con `pivot_longer()`
- Luego con el `group_by` y el `summarise_at()` agrupamos por cada grupo y sumarisamos para obtener los estádistico
- Lo único un poco más raro es el tratamiento de los cuantiles, que se transforman en una lista y se "descomprimen" en columnas.

Answer (score 3):

La función `summary` de R te da premisamente los datos que quiere para cada columna. La cuestión es que no están  en el formato que necesitas

```
 summary(MgClas)
 Pasto natural   Vegetación arbustiva baja (matorral y/o guamil)
 Min.   :35.46   Min.   :48.93                                  
 1st Qu.:40.78   1st Qu.:55.53                                  
 Median :40.92   Median :68.05                                  
 Mean   :45.26   Mean   :66.14                                  
 3rd Qu.:52.08   3rd Qu.:73.87                                  
 Max.   :57.04   Max.   :84.34                                  
 Lago, laguna o laguneta Humedal con vegetación Bosque latifoliado
 Min.   :48.89           Min.   :37.42          Min.   :60.03     
 1st Qu.:60.04           1st Qu.:47.16          1st Qu.:61.35     
 Median :62.11           Median :53.53          Median :73.10     
 Mean   :60.67           Mean   :57.17          Mean   :69.56     
 3rd Qu.:65.93           3rd Qu.:60.74          3rd Qu.:75.54     
 Max.   :66.38           Max.   :86.97          Max.   :77.80
```

Para obtenerlos como un `data.frame` puedes usar el siguiente código

```
Resumen<-as.data.frame(t(apply(MgClas, 2, summary)))
Resumen
                                                    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean
Pasto natural                                   35.45997 40.77836 40.91762 45.25714
Vegetación arbustiva baja (matorral y/o guamil) 48.92716 55.52616 68.04921 66.14180
Lago, laguna o laguneta                         48.88681 60.03544 62.11372 60.66885
Humedal con vegetación                          37.41736 47.16109 53.53387 57.16534
Bosque latifoliado                              60.02625 61.35207 73.10242 69.56442
                                                 3rd Qu.     Max.
Pasto natural                                   52.08484 57.04489
Vegetación arbustiva baja (matorral y/o guamil) 73.86934 84.33711
Lago, laguna o laguneta                         65.93312 66.37518
Humedal con vegetación                          60.74121 86.97318
Bosque latifoliado                              75.53647 77.80491
```

Que restaría es agregar una columna para el código y la categoría

```
Resumen$Categoria <- rownames(Resumen)
Resumen$cod <- 1:5 # Nota si los códigos no quedan bien revisa ?left_join para que los agregues dese otro df
```